# Ignite Annotations in Scala.Dynamic

Tags: scala, dynamic, annotations, ignite, gridgain

Currently I'm using GridGain/Ignite in my project and faced with some problems:

As you may know, GridGain can hold any serializable object in Cache, like this:

```
val mycache = ignite.getOrCreateCache[String,MyClass]("MyName")
```

It means, that we can define our class and extend it with Dynamic property - that's ok.

If we set Ignite-annotation (@QuerySqlField) at specific class-field - Ignite can use sql-queries with your classes like this:

```
val sql = select * from MyClass
mycache.query(new SqlFieldsQuers(sql))
```

And now my question:
How can I set Ignite-annotations with dynamic fields in dynamic classes in Scala? I've attached my dynamic class definition and hope for some help..

```
class DynamicType extends Dynamic with Serializable
{
private val fields = mutable.Map.empty[String,Any].withDefault{key=>throw new NoSuchFieldError(key)}
def selectDynamic(key: String) = fields(key)
def updateDynamic(key: String)(value: Any) = fields(key) = value
def applyDynamic(key: String)(args: Any*) = fields(key)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your dynamic type implementation will represent just a map of fields. In this case Ignite will serialize that map as `DynamicType` instance field. So it's like any object with field of `Map` type. Map's key/value pairs can't be annotated and can't be indexed by Ignite.

Comment: Generally, SQL schema is currently static in Ignite. So I doubt it can work with dynamic objects in the first place.

Comment: @ValentinKulichenko It will in case of programmatically creation of cache/schema.